# javascript: searching text including html and changing its css style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension, which can find a text in a webpage and make it bold.
When I find a simple text, it works, however, it does not work when an original text includes html tag.

Here are my codes,

```
$("p:contains(" + "like apple" + )").html(
  function( _ , html ) {
    return html.split("like apple").join("<b>" + "like apple" + "/b>");
  }
)
```

For example, 
if I find word "like apple", in `<p>I like apple</p>`, it becomes `<p>I <b>like apple</b></p>`.

However, for `<p>I like <i>apple</i></p>`, the code can not find the words "like apple" because of `<i>`.

How can I fix the code, which can find a text including html tags and change its css style?

Answer (score 1):

test if text contains html elements if it has, strip html element to get text.

```
var text='like <span>apple<span/>'

if(/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(text)){
var stripped_text=strip(text);
}

function strip(html)
{
var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
tmp.innerHTML = html;
return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted it for multiple text replacements:

```
var customText = ['like apples', 'more apples'];

customText.forEach(function(item){

  $("p:contains(" +item +")").html(
    function( _ , html ) {
      return html.split(item).join("<b>" + item + "</b>");
    }
  )

})

<p>I like apples therefore i will buy more apples today.</p>
```